# LUA C API - weak references with luaL_ref

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

With the following example:

```
int r = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

`r` will be a strong reference to an object on top of a stack.

Is it possible to get a weak reference to the top object on the stack?

One of the approaches I was thinking about is to create a table with weak values and store it inside the global registry. Then use that when a weak value is needed.

Is there an easier approach?

Lua 2.4 had this in the documentation, but `luaL_ref` seems to work differently now.:

> The function lua_ref creates a reference to the object which is on the
>   top of the stack, and returns this reference. If lock is true, the
>   object is locked: that means the object will not be garbage collected

Comment: possible duplicate of [seeking a "weak Lua registry"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854976/seeking-a-weak-lua-registry)

Comment: @Kamiccolo This question is specific to `luaL_ref`. I was looking for a C API solution on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
int create_ref(bool weak_ref)
{
    lua_newtable(L); // new_table={}

    if (weak_ref) {
        lua_newtable(L); // metatable={}            

        lua_pushliteral(L, "__mode");
        lua_pushliteral(L, "v");
        lua_rawset(L, -3); // metatable._mode='v'

        lua_setmetatable(L, -2); // setmetatable(new_table,metatable)
    }

    lua_pushvalue(L,-2); // push the previous top of stack
    lua_rawseti(L,-2,1); // new_table[1]=original value on top of the stack

    //Now new_table is on top of the stack, rest is up to you
    //Here is how you would store the reference:
    return luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // this pops the new_table
}
```

With this function I can store weak and strong references. With only 1 extra table as overhead (or 1+metatable for weak references).

Comment: Yes, this is the only real way of doing it, except for uservalues tied to userdata values which are also weak. But this route is specific to using userdata objects and may not be applicable to your case.